# facebook integration with objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

My App was work fine, before few days it become crash and give this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0'
```

When I check the plist file I found that the fbauth2 is there as it should be:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>twitter</string>
    <string>twitterauth</string>
</array>
```

any one have any idea about that?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
You only need to add into your Info.plist. You have to add 
<string>fb-messenger-api</string> for iOS 9.0

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: If still you are facing the issue then you can check the following link, this may help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9.                     
                                                                                                     
 Please once again check the following steps:- 1. Go to info.plist 2. Add a field namely LSApplicationQueriesSchemes NSArray datatype. 3. Add an item of NSString datatype name it as fbauth2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

In your `info.plist`, add a row with the key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. Make sure it is of `array` type. For it's only element, add the string `fbauth2`.

[image]